# KML Polystyle colour not showing

Tags: r, google-maps, kml

I'm trying to generate a custom map on Google's MyMaps using a KML file exported from R. I'm expecting a chloropleth map - a series of polygons each filled with a colour that is based on a separate variable.

I've pasted a simplified structure of the KML file below - there are actually 98 polygons in the actual file, each with their own `Style id`.

My question is why, when I import this file as a layer in MyMaps, the colour of the polygons are all shown as black? I would've thought that, since they all have a `PolyStyle' tag with a 'color' value, that they should all be displayed with separate colours.
I've tried clearing the cache for MyMaps but that hasn't seemed to do anything.

```
<kml xmlns:xsd="https://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd" xmlns:xmlns="https://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2/" version="1.0">
  <Document>
    <name>map_test2_1</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Folder>
      <name>sfdata.frame</name>
      <Style id="poly1">
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>#ff445eb5</color>
          <outline>1</outline>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
        <BalloonStyle>
          <text>$[description]</text>
        </BalloonStyle>
      </Style>
     <Placemark>
        <name>School Lane/Tankerton Road Area</name>
        <styleUrl>#poly1</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
          <extrude>1</extrude>
          <tessellate>0</tessellate>
          <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
          <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
              <coordinates>-0.3060805,51.402915,0
 -0.2748381,51.3823493,0
 -0.2552687,51.4096612,0
 -0.3060805,51.402915,0</coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
          </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
      </Placemark>
  </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: You have a typo, `<color>#ff445eb5</color>` should be `<color>ff445eb5</color>` ([your KML with that modification](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20221101_PolyStyleC.kml))

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be using HTML colors, which won't work in KML.  First, remove the "#" at the beginning of the color.  Then, be aware that the colors in KML are encoded as AABBGGRR (AA = alpha/opacity, BB = blue, GG = green, RR = red).  Html and most other color encodings use RGB order, but KML is reversed and uses BGR.

If that doesn't fix it, then try looking at the winding direction of your polygons, and make sure the vertices are encoded in Counter-Clockwise order.  If they are in clockwise order, then the polygon might get rendered upside-down, with the "shadow side" facing up.